# UITextView hidekeyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uitextview

I am trying to send message with photo to evernote. I created view for this

first I put `UITextField` for Title 
Then I put `UITextView` for message and given a button to attach photo and have one image view to hold image from `UIImagePicker`. When I write some text in `UITextView` keyboard will cover attach photo button and image button. How to hide keyboard...or can I minimize height of keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a background button and when user is done with typing text view message, you can expect the user to tap somewhere outside so that this background button takes the tap event and dismisses the keyboard.

Something as follows:

```
-(IBAction) backgroundButtonPressed:(id) sender {
    [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to minimize the height you can slide up the view and and after enter the text you need to hide the keyboard so for this,

Hide keyboard- Either add a tool bar above the keyboard or add a bar button in nav bar. and on click of the button

```
[youTextView resignFirstResponder];
```

for add tool bar make tool bar below the view make and when tap the text View a delegate will call `textViewShouldBeganEditing`  in this write some thing like this

```
 CGRect tlFrame=yourToolBar.frame;
  tlFrame.origin.y-=40;  //check this according to you
  yourToolBar.frame=tlFrame.origin.y;
```

also add some animation and , make its origin.y as it is when hide the keyboard.

Comment: I used https://github.com/cwalcott/UIToolbar-Keyboard-Example to hide keyboard with toolbar.But in this example in interface builder when I clicked on toolbar it is not showing.and in my code it is always visible in nib.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the keyboard then how do you expect the user to input the message? And you can customize the keyboard to change its height. One ideal way to do it is to move your view up so that when the keyboard comes, the button and image are still visible.

Comment: No I want to hide keyboard after user completes writing and then go to attach photo button

Comment: use [yourTextField resignFirstResponder]; after completing entry

Answer (score 0):

Well for this you can animate the view as..

```
CGFloat animatedDistance;   // in.h file
```

and in .m file do the following

```
#pragma mark (Text View Delegate Method)
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
    static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
    static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
    static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
    static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

    CGRect textFieldRect;
    CGRect viewRect;

    textFieldRect =[self.view.window convertRect:textView.bounds fromView:textView];
    viewRect =[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];


    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame;

    viewFrame= self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textView.tag==0)
    {
        static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
        CGRect viewFrame;

        viewFrame= self.view.frame;
        viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];


        [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];



    }
}
```

This will solve your problem,so that nothing would be hidden there

Answer (score 0):

Call this method in done button

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return NO;
}
```